# How do I properly configure Firefox 7 on Windows 7 to use Outlook for mailto links?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, microsoft-outlook, mailto

I have Outlook open. In Firefox, I click a mailto: link. Instead of opening a new message, it opens up a new instance of Outlook, which doesn't work.

My problem is basically exactly as described in [KB312346](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312346)

Unfortunately, the solution presented is not for Windows 7 and I can't figure out how to add the `-c IPM.Note /m "%1"` part of the application string.

In the `Tools > Options` menu, I have `mailto`: set to use Outlook, but in the application details, it lists just `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\OUTLOOK.EXE`. How do I add the extra settings to that?

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that the mailto link is correct **[rawurlencode](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.rawurlencode.php)**?

I had the same problem. After hours of search. I found out that the mailto link(s) was not encodet.

Comment: Please update this answer with the actual change (from the link?) that needs to be done for a new Outlook message Window to open.

Comment: While I'm not sure if it is properly encoded or not, I do know that the mailto: link works properly using other browsers and on other computers. It is not just one mailto: link, but every mailto: link I click on.